# ExtJS 4.1 how to set a preselected item in a combo box?

Tags: extjs4.1

I'm working with ExtJS 4.1, I need to create a combo box containing a list of name and I'd like to set a specific pre-selected item in it, but I don't know how to do it. Here's the code to create my combo box:

```
{
                            xtype         : 'combo',
                            fieldLabel    : 'Pay Method',                               
                            triggerAction : 'all',
                            forceSelection: true,
                            store         : 'S01I011001',
                            editable      : false,
                            emptyText     : 'Please Select',
                            name          : 'payMethodId',
                            typeAhead     : true,
                            queryMode     : 'remote',
                            displayField  : 'name',
                            valueField    : 'id',
                            id            : 'payMethod-t00700106',
                            listeners  :{                               
                                'select': {
                                    fn: function (combo, value) {
                                        var value=combo.getValue();                              
                                        if(value != null || value != ''){                              
                                            if(value == '2' || value == '3'){
                                                Ext.getCmp('return-t00700106').disable();
                                            }else{
                                                Ext.getCmp('return-t00700106').enable();
                                            }
                                        }
                                    }
                                }                    
                            }
                        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do it in this way , And activated store property autoLoad : true

```
                          {
                            xtype         : 'combo',
                            fieldLabel    : 'Pay Method',                               
                            triggerAction : 'all',
                            forceSelection: true,
                            store         : 'S01I011001',
                            editable      : false,
                            emptyText     : 'Please Select',
                            name          : 'payMethodId',
                            typeAhead     : true,
                            queryMode     : 'remote',
                            displayField  : 'name',
                            valueField    : 'id',
                            id            : 'payMethod-t00700106',
                            listeners     :{
                                boxready  : function(){
                                  this.setValue(this.getStore().getAt(0).get(this.valueField),true);
                                      this.fireEvent('select',this);
                                      }
                                  }
                            }
```

Answer (score 2):

Just use the 'value' property, and set it to the code value of the entry you want.

Comment: If my store is empty than what will